# Restart a process in detached screen via ssh

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

I have a server with several screens running, each with their own node server listing to different ports. I'd like to create Jenkins jobs to ssh into the box, reattach a specific screen, stop the process, pull from git, restart the app, and detach the screen. Can you 'stuff' a Ctrl+C into a screen? Thinking something along the lines of:

```
ssh myuser@myserver "screen -S 1234.myscreen -X stuff '[[Ctrl+C]] && git pull origin master && npm install && node app' [[Detach screen]]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ctrl+C sends a SIGINT. So if you can determine the PID of the process you want to signal, you can do `kill -INT pid` before the `git pull`, or `killall -INT processname` if you want to stop them all, assuming your `killall` does not behave like `killall5`.

As for scripting the detachment of a screen session, I've no idea. Perhaps someone else can help you there.

EDIT: It just occured to me that you don't need to script the detachment or indeed do anything with screen. Simply execute something like this inside screen:

```
while sleep 1; do
    ./some_program      # which saves its PID to a pidfile
    git pull
done
```

And then you can execute this from outside screen, over ssh:

```
kill -INT $(cat pidfile)
```

If your process does not save a pidfile, you can try to use start-stop-daemon to have it do that:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --exec ./some_program --pidfile pidfile --make-pidfile
```

Comment: This put me on the right track. I ended up using upstart scripts.

Answer (score 1):

The Ctrl+C sequence must be entered as a literal ^C character:
<kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> (allows insertion of a literal character), then <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>

When the `stuff` command is used screen doesn't interactively attach the session so it isn't necessary to detach.  You may, however, need a carriage return after the last command, entered as a literal:
<kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd>